# Armazenagem indevida no vetor

Tags: c, array

Estou tendo problemas para resolver esse algoritmo em c. preciso que o usuario digite 10 numeros, e verificar se o numero é par ou impar. armazenar esses numeros em dois vetores distintos, um para os numeros pares e outro para os impares. Porém, estou com duvida sobre o que eu faço com os espaços dos vetores nos quais nao fica armazenado nenhum dado do usuário, pois ele geralmente retorna lixo da memória. Segue o código: 
'''
int main()
{
    int i,num,qtdP,qtdI,impares[max],pares[max];

```
qtdP=qtdI=0;


for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    //entrada de dados do usuario
    printf("Digite um numero: ");scanf("%d",&num);

    //verifica se o numero é par ou impar, e armazena no seu devido vetor
    if(num%2==0){

        pares[qtdP]=num;
        qtdP++;
    }else{

        impares[qtdI]=num;
        qtdI++;
    }
}

//imprime os numeros pares
printf("\n\nOs numeros pares sao: ");
for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    printf("%d ",pares[i]);
    qtdP++;
}

//imprime os numeros impares
printf("\nOs numeros impares sao: ");
for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    printf("%d ",impares[i]);
    qtdI++;
}


return 0;
```

}'''

Comment: Simplesmente ignore tais posições. Seus loops para impressão não devem ser `for(i=0;i<10;i++){` e sim ir até `qtdP` e `qtdI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não declarou a variável `max` usada para inicializar os arrays `pares` e `impares`, por isso eu substitui pelo valor 10.

Movi as variáveis `i` e `num` para o escopo em que elas são usadas.

E para que o programa imprima apenas os valores validos dos arrays você deve limitar os loops for usando as variáveis `qtdP` e `qtdI`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int qtdP = 0, pares[10];
  int qtdI = 0, impares[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int num = 0;

    //entrada de dados do usuario
    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    //verifica se o numero é par ou impar, e armazena no seu devido vetor
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      pares[qtdP] = num;
      qtdP++;
    } else {
      impares[qtdI] = num;
      qtdI++;
    }
  }

  //imprime os numeros pares
  printf("\n\nOs numeros pares sao: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < qtdP; i++) {
    printf("%d ", pares[i]);
  }

  //imprime os numeros impares
  printf("\nOs numeros impares sao: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < qtdI; i++) {
    printf("%d ", impares[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```